# Google Finance Function in Google Sheets is excluding todays price when looking back over a series of days?

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, google-finance

I have here a picture of [What I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg3bj.jpg) I want the previous 5 days closing prices in a column including todays price. The problem is that I only get 4 date prices (cell range F6:F9) excluding todays date price (cell F3).

I understand that the date is not in the correct format in cell range E6:E9, but I don't care for this, as I only care for the close prices in column F (cell range F6:F9)

Below is the code that I have in the cell E5:
`=index(GOOGLEFINANCE($A5,"price",workday(today(),-5),TODAY()))`

---

Here is a picture of [What I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxJmn.jpg) I want code for cell E12.

Below is the code in cell F3:
`=GOOGLEFINANCE(A3,"price")`

Thanks.

Comment: it takes time to appear under closed

Comment: could you do it for mid/average/median? anything to get the average of todays date (instead of just seeing only yesterdays) would be appreciated so I can look at it as a column in a cell visually with the "Sparkline" function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(A5, "price", WORKDAY(TODAY(), -5), TODAY()),,2); 
 GOOGLEFINANCE(A5, "price")}
```

Comment: Thank You. This is exactly what I need. I can see it visually when I look up my watchlists during the day without going to each individual detail chart.